# Upload of large files using Suave?

Tags: f#, suave

I would like to upload files using Suave. I understand that small files will automatically get written to a `/tmp` folder, but my files are too large for that. What I would like to do is process them as a *stream* and send them to long term storage, via the Suave server.

Here is my server:

```ml
#r "nuget: Suave"

open System.IO
open Suave
open Suave.Sockets
open Suave.Sockets.Control

let config = defaultConfig

let socketTask (conn : Connection, httpResult : HttpResult) =
  socket {
    printfn "Started socket task"

    use stream = new TransportStream (conn.transport)
    use reader = new StreamReader (stream)

    while not reader.EndOfStream do
      printfn "Reading... "

      let! line = SocketOp.ofAsync (async {
        let! line = reader.ReadLineAsync ()
        return line
      })

      printfn "%s" line

    printfn "Finished socket task"

    return conn
  }

let app : WebPart =
  (fun ctx -> async {
    printfn "Received request"

    return
      Some
        {
          ctx with
            response =
              {
                ctx.response with
                  content = SocketTask socketTask
              }
        }
  })

startWebServer config app
```

But when I run this `curl` command, it just hangs:

```sh
$ curl -X POST --data-binary @big-file.csv localhost:8080
```

```sh
$ dotnet fsi ./Suave.fsx
[17:32:05 INF] Smooth! Suave listener started in 14.279ms with binding 127.0.0.1:8080
Received request
Started socket task
```

I would expect the uploaded file to be printed line-by-line.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm able to reproduce what you're seeing and am trying to debug now. I have some experience with Suave, but haven't used their socket support before. There doesn't seem to be any documentation. Would you consider using WebSockets instead? There's an example here: https://suave.io/websockets.html

Comment: After looking at this for a while, I suspect that what you're trying to do here is simply not supported. If you try to read directly from the underlying connection, the call will block because the client is waiting for a response, rather than actively sending additional data. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: @brianberns That was my suspicion too, but thought it was worth asking. I will investigate Giraffe...

Comment: I have no idea whether this is the issue, but I once tried to write a Suave server that would accept largeish uploads (not massive though) and I had to set the `maxContentLength` parameter of the `defaultConfig` to get it to work: https://github.com/the-gamma/gallery-web/blob/master/src/release.fs#L12 Would that help?

Comment: @TomasPetricek That does indeed help, but uploads are still constrained by server disc space

Comment: @sdgfsdh Yeah, that's what I was afraid of - I don't know anything else that could help!